# mongodb service on debian

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian

I have installed monogodb with this procedure :
[Mongodb on Debian](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

The service mongod is running.

```
$ service mongod status

mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-11-04 09:29:04 CET; 1 weeks 5 days ago
Main PID: 957 (mongod)
  CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
          └─957 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

Nov 04 09:29:04 serv01 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
```

I didn't find the init script of this instance :

```
$ service --status-all | grep mon

  [ + ]  smartmontools
```

and `whereis mongod`:

```
mongod: /usr/bin/mongod /etc/mongod.conf /usr/share/man/man1/mongod.1.gz
```

Where is the mongod init script stored?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls /etc/init.d/mongodb`?

Comment: ls /etc/init.d/mongo*
ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/mongo*: No such file or directory